# How to install the pylzma python library on Linux?

Tags: python, libraries

The pylzma library is a requirement for another tool that I would like to use. I am new to python and programming and have a few questions:

I have already followed the procedure to download and install pylzma from the following site since it seems to be the easiest: https://code.google.com/p/threadzip/wiki/InstallingPylzma

But I get stuck at the byte compile py7zlib part.

How do I byte compile py7zlib?

When I check the documentation on the authors page http://www.joachim-bauch.de/projects/pylzma/ and go to the designated folder I see the following files:

In the `/tmp/pylzma-0.4.6/build/lib.linux-i686-2.7` folder I see: `py7lib.py` `py7zlib.pyc` `pylzma.so`

But no the "py7zlib.pwd" as stated on the authors page however I do see the "py7zlib.pyc" as stated on the original page listed.

Do I still need to compile this bytecode?

When I "import python" in at the python prompt I see nothing, no feedback or error. How do I check to see if this has been correctly imported and that I have installed this library correctly?

Comment: `import python` at the Python prompt should print an error message: `ImportError: No module named python` (after a couple of lines of traceback info). But what happens if you do `import pylzma` at the python prompt?

Comment: You are correct - that is a mistake I meant to say "import pylzma"

Comment: What is the other tool? Are you sure it is dependent on pylzma and not on the newer lzma module? which distro are you on?

Comment: SWFZip is the other tool and I am on Ubuntu.

Comment: You don't get any feedback in the Python interactive interpreter with a successful import. But after importing pylzma if you do `help(pylzma)` you should get some helpful info.

Answer (score 1):

Those are several questions so lets start at the beginning:

1. I don't know why instructions for Python 2.6 from 2012 seem the simplest, but in general you should:

   - install using your package manager e.g on Debian/Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install python-lzma` (this is the backport of the the standard lzma module that appeared in Python3.3)
   - or install from [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pylzma/0.4.6) using pip (which has to be installed only once):

     ```
     sudo apt-get install python-pip
     pip install pylzma
     ```

   Both these methods allow you to deinstall, something starting from the tar doesn't guarantee. Using pip normally gives you a more up-to-date package, but cannot handle system library dependencies (so you might have to install the package `liblzma5` if not already installed.
2. You don't normally bytecompile explicitly, at the latest on first use this is done, or during setup. But python works ok with `.py` files even if it cannot write the `.pyc` on first use (it just starts slower).
3. I wonder why `import python` at the python prompt doesn't give an error. On my system it does, as there is no file `python.py`. To test if you have pylzma you could follow the instructions on [the outdated page you refer](https://code.google.com/p/threadzip/wiki/InstallingPylzma) to:

   ```
   >>> import pylzma
   >>> import py7zlib
   ```

---

Using `pip` I got version 0.4.6 of Igor Pavlov's bindings

Comment: I have a fresh Ubuntu 14.10 version. Just created this VM.

Comment: user@ubuntu:~$ python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Oct 20 2014, 15:05:19) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux2

Comment: Both python-lzma and python-pip installed correctly. There appears to be no error messages.

Comment: When I do pip install pylzma that is when I have problems: creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/compat

x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-strict-aliasing -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -fPIC -DWITH_COMPAT=1 -DPYLZMA_VERSION="0.4.6" -Isrc/sdk -I/usr/include/python2.7 -c src/pylzma/pylzma.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-2.7/src/pylzma/pylzma.o

Comment: src/pylzma/pylzma.c:26:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory

 #include <Python.h>

                    ^

compilation terminated.

error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: both import pylzma and import py7zlib fail.

Comment: Tried easy_install and received this error: 
Processing pylzma-0.4.6.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-xwbezh/pylzma-0.4.6/setup.cfg
Running pylzma-0.4.6/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-xwbezh/pylzma-0.4.6/egg-dist-tmp-oOEFFb
warning: no files found matching '*.py' under directory 'test'
warning: no files found matching '*.7z' under directory 'test'
no previously-included directories found matching 'src/sdk.orig'
/tmp/easy_install-xwbezh/pylzma-0.4.6/setup.py:107:

Comment: UnsupportedPlatformWarning: Multithreading is not supported on the platform "linux2",
please contact mail@joachim-bauch.de for more informations.
  please contact mail@joachim-bauch.de for more informations.""" % (sys.platform), UnsupportedPlatformWarning)
src/pylzma/pylzma.c:26:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include <Python.h>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: Setup script exited with error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Comment: Because of Multithreading I have not found a way to do this in Linux. I switched to Python in Windows and downloaded the correct version of the Windows binary from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pylzma and it installed without any issues.

Comment: @S.Poon You can resolve the fatal error by installing package `python-dev` or `libpython2.7-dev`. I am not sure why you didn't do that. That that works on Windows is because you installed with headers files and all, which you did not do on Ubuntu. Googling for "Python.h missing ubuntu" gives you that solution.